# dataGridView.Rows.DataBoundItem Return NULL

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a dataGridView, I need reference the object what create the first row, I use

`var p1 = (Proceso) dataGridView2.Rows[0].DataBoundItem as Proceso;`

Full code

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            string[] datosAObjetos = new string[5];
            datosAObjetos[0] = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value);
            datosAObjetos[1] = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value);
            datosAObjetos[2] = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value);
            datosAObjetos[3] = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3].Value);
            datosAObjetos[4] = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[4].Value);

            var procesoOBJ = new Proceso();

            procesoOBJ.identificadorProceso = datosAObjetos[0];
            procesoOBJ.nombreProceso = datosAObjetos[1];
            procesoOBJ.quantumProceso = datosAObjetos[2];
            procesoOBJ.rutaOrigenProceso = datosAObjetos[3];
            procesoOBJ.rutaDestinoProceso = datosAObjetos[4];

            dataGridView2.Rows.Add(procesoOBJ.identificadorProceso,procesoOBJ.quantumProceso);

        }

           var p1 = (Proceso) dataGridView2.Rows[0].DataBoundItem as Proceso;               

           if (p1 != null)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(p1.identificadorProceso);
           }
    }
```

what happend ?

Answer (score -2):

```
DataRowView drv =   dataGridView2.Rows[0].DataBoundItem as DataRowView ;
if(drv != null)
{
    DataRow row = drv.Row;
    var p1= row as Proceso;
}
```

Comment: Can not convert type 'System.Data.DataRow' in 'Simulador.Proceso' by reference conversion, boxing, unboxing, setting type text or null

Comment: did you also try `var p1= (Proceso) row `?

Comment: Yes [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ilpbtvq0bbwvkzq/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202015-04-04%2017.14.23.png?dl=0) See the image , drv == null

Comment: can you try this : `Proceso p1 = (Proceso) row as Proceso`

Comment: What if you just use this  `row["identificadorProceso"];` I see that you only print out that value, then why bother converting it to Proceso, we can just use `row["identificadorProceso"];` ? What do you think?

Comment: No work , I need move this Process OBJ to others dataGridView ( I have 5 dataGridViews and I need reference the same object in all ), becouse the properties change for each object.

Comment: however, this way you can not create a reference to all rows that display that object. If its properties change, you will see no change in other datagridviews.